# Handling missing value in column having textual data

Tags: data-cleaning, text-classification

I have been working on a supervised ML use case where dataset has Numerical (Price), Categorical(Category) and Textual data(Description) as features. Description feature has about 30% missing values. I don’t want to drop them as data set is small and it would cause information loss. Looking for any suggestion on how to handle missing value ?

Answer (score 0):

A "missing text" can be considered simply an empty text, and an empty text is still a valid text: as long as the design of the code doesn't assume non-empty text, it should not cause any issue. In particular it can be consistently encoded with bag of words representations.